How to log apollo errors on NestJS?
I have a very small NestJS project with GraphQL. According to their docs, you can catch every error using a ExceptionFilter, so that's what I did and here is my ExceptionFilter:
@Catch()
export class ExceptionFilter implements GqlExceptionFilter {
  constructor(private logger: Logger) {}

  catch(exception: HttpException): HttpException {
    this.logger.error(exception.message, exception.stack, ExceptionFilter.name);

    return exception;
  }
}

I just want to log all errors. The problem here is that if Apollo throws an error, like an input or output validation error for example, it won't log, in fact, the ExceptionFilter won't catch the error.
How can I make sure my ExceptionFilter catches the Apollo errors or what is the reason and how to log the Apollo errors on my application?
This is my GraphQL config:
@Module({})
export class GraphqlModule extends NestGraphQLModule {
  static forRootAsync(
    options?: GqlModuleOptions<GraphQLDriver<ApolloDriverConfig>>,
  ): DynamicModule {
    return super.forRootAsync({
      driver: ApolloDriver,
      useFactory: async () => ({
        playground: false,
        autoSchemaFile: true,
        plugins: [
          ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault(),
          ApolloServerPluginInlineTrace(),
        ],
        context: ({ req }) => ({ req }),
        csrfPrevention: false,
        introspection: true,
        ...options,
      }),
    });
  }
}

